# PHP Mysql List table with Code in table will only work on first line item

Tags: php

I have a list table that on the end of each line i have a delete record and a stamp file. My code works on the first record in the list but not on any other lines. what am *i* missing. I am using `Javascript` and `Ajax` with my `Buttons`.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM scanns WHERE `site` = '$csite' AND `date` BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' ";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['site']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="scann/<?php echo $row['site']?>/<?php echo  $row['file_name'] ?>" target="_blank">view scann</a></td>
        <input id='date'type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['date']; ?>"/>
       <input id='site'type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['site']; ?>"/>
        <input id='filename' type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>"/>
        <td><input id="submit"  type="button" value="Delete Scan"></td>
        <td><input id="stamp"  type="button" value="Post File"></td>
         </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
```

This is the complete file

```
    <?php
require_once("../config.php");

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
        die('could not connect: ' .mysqli_error($link));
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Car\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' .mysqli_error($link));
}

$csite = $_POST['site'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];

//var_dump($_POST);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>name</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/refreshform.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jvscripts/form.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="Main_files/css3menu0/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}
<script>



</script>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="/images/logo1.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="998" height="102" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #424542; display:block;" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section -->
  <div class="sidebar1">
<?php
include ('menu/menu.php');
?>

</div>

  <div class="content">
  <p style="text-align:center"><img src="cloudscan.png" width="100" height="60" alt="" align="middle" /></p>
<p><h3 style="width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; color: black;">You have Selected the Store <?php echo $csite;?> </h3></p>
<p span style="background-color: #2C3539; color: #FFF;"font color: #FFFFFF>Listed Documents from date :<?php echo $sdate;?> to <?php echo $edate;?>.</p>
<table width="98%" border="1">

    <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Site</td>
    <td>File</td>
    <td>View</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
    <td>Post</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM scanns WHERE `site` = '$csite' AND `date` BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' ";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['site']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="scann/<?php echo $row['site']?>/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" target="_blank">view scann</a></td>
        <td><input id='date' type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['date']; ?>"/><input id='site' type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['site']; ?>"/><input id='filename' type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>"/><input id="submit"  type="button" value="Delete Scan"></td>
        <td><input id="stamp"  type="button" value="Post File"></td>
         </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>

<button id="btnsubmit" onclick="goBack()">Change Site and date</button> 

   </div>



<script>
function goBack() {
    window.location.href='cssites.php';
}


</script>





  <div class="footer">
    <p>"Successful people are always looking for opportunities to help others. Unsuccessful people are always asking, "What's in it for me?'' "</p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing some spaces on the date and site hidden lines... could be causing issues perhaps.

Comment: You also have some inputs there not wrapped in <td></td> so they will break out of the table.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed those two items but still will only work on the first line  item and not on any other items

Comment: Can you please include the data/table you are using??

Comment: Thank to all I have resolved this had to change the id to class